# android sdk version 3.0 minSdkVersion

Tags: android, versioning, android-manifest

I am trying to make android program with android sdk version 3.0, but I have some errors.
"minSdkVersion(7) is lower than the project target API level(11)".
what is the reason is this?

Comment: show your app's manifest.xml file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tag in your `androidmanifest.xml`, like

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

It describes which Android version is needed at minimum to run your application
If you want your application to run on Honeycomb (and nothing below like 2.x) correct the number to `11`

Answer (score 2):

In your AndroidManifest.xml you set as minimum required version Android 2.1 (API 7), but you have a build target of Android 3.0 (API 11).

If your target really is Android 3.0 and higher, then set in the manifest file the following line:
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />`

If not, then you also have to install the Android SDK for version 2.1 (or the version you really want as a minimum sdk version).

See also:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html

Answer (score 2):

Because you specified a minSdkVersion less than the targetSdkVersion attribute in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Anyway, don't worry about the warning. This behavior it's normal when you create an app that use some api 11 specific features (themes, resources, etc) but can downgrade to api 7 without problems...

Answer (score 1):

you should have something like this in your androidmanifest.xml

uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"

you should change it to the version you are looking for